# VBA Dynamic Ranges - how do I copy formulas to NEW last row? Dynamic; named column headers

Tags: excel, vba

**My Problem**

I have several columns that are dynamically identified by their column header names.  I want to be able to copy formulas down to the NEW last row after pasting in data from another sheet.  HEADER_NAME_1 - 5 are the items which I am copying from another Worksheet into the "Report" Worksheet.  HEADER_NAME_6 "Unique ID" is a formula (there are additional HEADER_NAMES_X as well; 7,8,9, etc.) that I would like copied down to the new end of the "Report" Worksheet.  I want the columns to be dynamic so that it doesn't matter where people have them located in their "Report" tab; that it only matter that the Header Names are spelled correctly.  I have been able to achieve this with everything else that I am doing within this spreadsheet, except for this.

```
Sub Auto_Add()
Dim wsK, wsR As Worksheet
Set wsR = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
Set wsK = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("KOB1")
Dim LR, LC, FR, LR1 As Long
Dim r1, r2, ra, rb, rc, rd, re, Rng, HeaderRow, rngHeaders, rngHdrFound1, rngHdrFound2, rngHdrFound3, rngHdrFound4, rngHdrFound5, rngHdrFound6 As Range

FR = wsR.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
LR = wsR.Range("A3").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
LC = wsR.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column

wsR.Select
Set Rng = Range(Cells(FR, 1), Cells(LR, LC))
Set HeaderRow = Range(Cells(FR, 1), Cells(FR, LC))

Const HEADER_NAME_1 As String = "Order Number"
Const HEADER_NAME_2 As String = "CE Groups"
Const HEADER_NAME_3 As String = "Vendor"
Const HEADER_NAME_4 As String = "PO"
Const HEADER_NAME_5 As String = "Current Month Actuals"
Const HEADER_NAME_6 As String = "Unique ID"

Set rngHeaders = Intersect(wsR.UsedRange, wsR.Rows(FR))
Set rngHdrFound1 = rngHeaders.Find(HEADER_NAME_1)
Set rngHdrFound2 = rngHeaders.Find(HEADER_NAME_2)
Set rngHdrFound3 = rngHeaders.Find(HEADER_NAME_3)
Set rngHdrFound4 = rngHeaders.Find(HEADER_NAME_4)
Set rngHdrFound5 = rngHeaders.Find(HEADER_NAME_5)
Set rngHdrFound6 = rngHeaders.Find(HEADER_NAME_6)

Set OrderNumber = rngHdrFound1.End(xlDown).Offset(1) 'I have these as Offset so it will go to the next (blank) cell underneath
Set CEGroups = rngHdrFound2.End(xlDown).Offset(1)
Set Vendor = rngHdrFound3.End(xlDown).Offset(1)
Set PO = rngHdrFound4.End(xlDown).Offset(1)
Set CurrentMonthActuals = rngHdrFound5.End(xlDown).Offset(1)
Set UID = rngHdrFound6.End(xlDown) 'I do not have this as an offset so you are able to select the formula

'this code starts identifying and organizing fields for what I need to get from "KOB1" tab....

If wsK.FilterMode Then
wsK.ShowAllData
End If

If wsR.FilterMode Then
wsR.ShowAllData
End If

wsR.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=2

LR1 = wsK.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

wsK.Range("$A$7:$M" & LR1).AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="ADD"

wsK.Select

Set r1 = wsK.AutoFilter.Range
Set r2 = Intersect(r1.Offset(1, 0), r1)
Set ra = Intersect(r2, Columns(3))
Set rb = Intersect(r2, Columns(5))
Set rc = Intersect(r2, Columns(9))
Set rd = Intersect(r2, Columns(8))
Set re = Intersect(r2, Columns(10))

ra.Copy 'Order Number
OrderNumber.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False

'...rest of code to grab what I need to from the "KOB1" tab and paste into the "Report" tab, works just fine...

Dim LR2 As Long   'This is one way to identify the new Last Row after pasting from the code(s) above
With wsR
LR2 = .Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row
End With

'THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP (I THINK)!!!
UID.Copy
wsR.Range("A4:A" & LR2).Select`  'I don't want to have to specify the Column range (A, B, C, etc.. OR the Row # A4, B4, etc...) It needs to be dynamic
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

'This last bit works, BUT I would like to only copy from the last cell in the respective column used (UID in this instance) down to the new Last Row (LR2).  ALSO, I do not wish to specify the Column or Row position.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!! (:

**What I've Tried**

I have played around with AutoFill with no success...

```
Dim LR3 As Long
LR3 = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
UID.Select
Range("A" & LR3).AutoFill Destination:=Range("A" & LR3 & ":A")
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

**Again, what I need to do**

I need to figure out how to Copy UID (and the other variables) and paste them to LR2 (the new Last Row, newly created after pasting from 'KOB1' tab).

```
'Some of the other variables:

Const HEADER_NAME_7 As String = "Project Lead"
Const HEADER_NAME_8 As String = "Project Name"
Const HEADER_NAME_9 As String = "RPA"
Const HEADER_NAME_10 As String = "Order Name"
Const HEADER_NAME_11 As String = "Accrual Amount Expected"
Const HAEDER_NAME_12 As String = "Scrub Accrual?"
Const HEADER_NAME_13 As String = "Current Month Var"

Set rngHdrFound7 = rngHeaders.Find(HEADER_NAME_7)
Set rngHdrFound8 = rngHeaders.Find(HEADER_NAME_8)
Set rngHdrFound9 = rngHeaders.Find(HEADER_NAME_9)
Set rngHdrFound10 = rngHeaders.Find(HEADER_NAME_10)
Set rngHdrFound11 = rngHeaders.Find(HEADER_NAME_11)
Set rngHdrFound12 = rngHeaders.Find(HEADER_NAME_12)
Set rngHdrFound13 = rngHeaders.Find(HEADER_NAME_13)

Set ProjectLead = rngHdrFound7.End(xlDown)
Set ProjectName = rngHdrFound8.End(xlDown)
Set RPA = rngHdrFound9.End(xlDown)
Set OrderName = rngHdrFound10.End(xlDown)
Set AccrualAmountExpected = rngHdrFound11.End(xlDown)
Set ScrubAccrual = rngHdrFound12.End(xlDown)
Set CurrentMonthVar = rngHdrFound13.End(xlDown)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work... for anyone who cares, here's how:

```
 Sub Auto_Add()

 ADDtoReport = MsgBox("You are about to Add items from the 'KOB1' tab to the 
'Report' tab." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "If you have added any columns to the 
 original 'Report' tab, you will need to fill values down manually." & vbNewLine 
 & vbNewLine & "You cannot un-do adding items other than manually deleting 
 them." 
 & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Do you wish to continue?", vbYesNo, "Add to 
 Report?")
 If ADDtoReport = vbYes Then

Dim wsK, wsR As Worksheet
Set wsR = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
Set wsK = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("KOB1")
Dim LR, LC, FR, LR1 As Long
Dim r1, r2, ra, rb, rc, rd, re, rng, HeaderRow, rngHeaders, rngHdrFound1, 
rngHdrFound2, rngHdrFound3, rngHdrFound4, rngHdrFound5 As Range

If Trim(wsK.Range("B8").Value) = "" Then
WARNING = MsgBox("There is currently no data in the KOB1 template." & vbNewLine 
& vbNewLine & "If you have entered data, make sure cell B8 is not empty.", 
vbOKOnly, "WARNING")
Else

FR = wsR.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
LR = wsR.Range("A3").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
LC = wsR.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column

 If wsK.FilterMode Then
    wsK.ShowAllData
 End If
 If wsR.FilterMode Then
    wsR.ShowAllData
 End If

With Application
 .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 .ScreenUpdating = False
 .DisplayStatusBar = False
 .EnableEvents = False
 .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

wsR.Select
Set rng = Range(Cells(FR, 1), Cells(LR, LC))
Set HeaderRow = Range(Cells(FR, 1), Cells(FR, LC))

Const HEADER_NAME_1 As String = "Order Number"
Const HEADER_NAME_2 As String = "CE Groups"
Const HEADER_NAME_3 As String = "Vendor"
Const HEADER_NAME_4 As String = "PO"
Const HEADER_NAME_5 As String = "Current Month Actuals"

Set rngHeaders = Intersect(wsR.UsedRange, wsR.Rows(FR))
Set rngHdrFound1 = rngHeaders.Find(HEADER_NAME_1)
Set rngHdrFound2 = rngHeaders.Find(HEADER_NAME_2)
Set rngHdrFound3 = rngHeaders.Find(HEADER_NAME_3)
Set rngHdrFound4 = rngHeaders.Find(HEADER_NAME_4)
Set rngHdrFound5 = rngHeaders.Find(HEADER_NAME_5)

Set OrderNumber = rngHdrFound1.End(xlDown).Offset(1)
Set CEGroups = rngHdrFound2.End(xlDown).Offset(1)
Set Vendor = rngHdrFound3.End(xlDown).Offset(1)
Set PO = rngHdrFound4.End(xlDown).Offset(1)
Set CurrentMonthActuals = rngHdrFound5.End(xlDown).Offset(1)

wsR.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=2

LR1 = wsK.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'KOB1 Last Row

wsK.Range("$A$7:$M" & LR1).AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="ADD"

wsK.Select

Set r1 = wsK.AutoFilter.Range
Set r2 = Intersect(r1.Offset(1, 0), r1)
Set ra = Intersect(r2, Columns(3))
Set rb = Intersect(r2, Columns(5))
Set rc = Intersect(r2, Columns(9))
Set rd = Intersect(r2, Columns(8))
Set re = Intersect(r2, Columns(10))

ra.Copy 'Order Number
OrderNumber.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

rb.Copy 'CE Group
CEGroups.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

rc.Copy 'Vendor
Vendor.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

rd.Copy 'PO
PO.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

re.Copy 'KOB1 Paid
CurrentMonthActuals.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Dim LR2 As Long 'New last row
With wsR
LR2 = .Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, 
False).Row
End With

Dim LR3 As Long 'Previous last row
With wsR
LR3 = wsR.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

wsR.Select

Dim ColUID As Integer: ColUID = WorksheetFunction.Match("Unique ID", rngHeaders, 
0)
Dim ColProjectLead As Integer: ColProjectLead = WorksheetFunction.Match("Project 
Lead", rngHeaders, 0)
Dim ColProjectName As Integer: ColProjectName = WorksheetFunction.Match("Project 
Name", rngHeaders, 0)
Dim ColRPA As Integer: ColRPA = WorksheetFunction.Match("RPA", rngHeaders, 0)
Dim ColOrderName As Integer: ColOrderName = WorksheetFunction.Match("Order 
Name", rngHeaders, 0)
Dim ColAccrualAmountExpected As Integer: ColAccrualAmountExpected = 
WorksheetFunction.Match("Accrual Amount Expected", rngHeaders, 0)
Dim ColScrubAccrual As Integer: ColScrubAccrual = WorksheetFunction.Match("Scrub 
Accrual?", rngHeaders, 0)
Dim ColCurrentMonthVar As Integer: ColCurrentMonthVar = 
WorksheetFunction.Match("Current Month Var", rngHeaders, 0)
Dim ColActOrFC As Integer: ColActOrFC = WorksheetFunction.Match("Act/Fc", 
rngHeaders, 0)
Dim ColLabor As Integer: ColLabor = WorksheetFunction.Match("Labor", rngHeaders, 
0)
Dim ColBMcD As Integer: ColBMcD = WorksheetFunction.Match("BMcD", rngHeaders, 0)
Dim ColVeg As Integer: ColVeg = WorksheetFunction.Match("Veg", rngHeaders, 0)
Dim ColAdjVar As Integer: ColAdjVar = WorksheetFunction.Match("Adj Var", 
rngHeaders, 0)
Dim ColDelta As Integer: ColDelta = WorksheetFunction.Match("Delta", rngHeaders, 
0)
Dim ColISD As Integer: ColISD = WorksheetFunction.Match("In-Service Date", 
rngHeaders, 0)
Dim ColTPR As Integer: ColTPR = WorksheetFunction.Match("TPR Reversal", 
rngHeaders, 0)
Dim ColAccRev As Integer: ColAccRev = WorksheetFunction.Match("Accrual 
Reversal", rngHeaders, 0)
Dim ColPTD As Integer: ColPTD = WorksheetFunction.Match("Pending Through Date", 
rngHeaders, 0)
Dim ColPP As Integer: ColPP = WorksheetFunction.Match("Pending Payments", 
rngHeaders, 0)
Dim ColPT As Integer: ColPT = WorksheetFunction.Match("Paid Through", 
rngHeaders, 0)
Dim ColAccruals As Integer: ColAccruals = WorksheetFunction.Match("Accruals", 
rngHeaders, 0)
Dim ColCMF As Integer: ColCMF = WorksheetFunction.Match("Current Month 
Forecast", rngHeaders, 0)
Dim ColTPOA As Integer: ColTPOA = WorksheetFunction.Match("Total PO Amount", 
rngHeaders, 0)
Dim ColSTBD As Integer: ColSTBD = WorksheetFunction.Match("Still to be 
Delivered", rngHeaders, 0)

Cells(LR3, ColUID).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(LR3, ColUID), Cells(LR2, 
ColUID))
Cells(LR3, ColProjectLead).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(LR3, 
ColProjectLead), Cells(LR2, ColProjectLead))
Cells(LR3, ColProjectName).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(LR3, 
ColProjectName), Cells(LR2, ColProjectName))
Cells(LR3, ColRPA).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(LR3, ColRPA), Cells(LR2, 
ColRPA))
Cells(LR3, ColOrderName).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(LR3, ColOrderName), 
Cells(LR2, ColOrderName))
Cells(LR3, ColAccrualAmountExpected).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(LR3, 
ColAccrualAmountExpected), Cells(LR2, ColAccrualAmountExpected))
Cells(LR3, ColScrubAccrual).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(LR3, 
ColScrubAccrual), Cells(LR2, ColScrubAccrual))
Cells(LR3, ColCurrentMonthVar).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(LR3, 
ColCurrentMonthVar), Cells(LR2, ColCurrentMonthVar))
Cells(LR3, ColActOrFC).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(LR3, ColActOrFC), 
Cells(LR2, ColActOrFC))
Cells(LR3, ColLabor).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(LR3, ColLabor), 
Cells(LR2, ColLabor))
Cells(LR3, ColBMcD).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(LR3, ColBMcD), Cells(LR2, 
ColBMcD))
Cells(LR3, ColVeg).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(LR3, ColVeg), Cells(LR2, 
ColVeg))
Cells(LR3, ColAdjVar).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(LR3, ColAdjVar), 
Cells(LR2, ColAdjVar))
Cells(LR3, ColDelta).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(LR3, ColDelta), 
Cells(LR2, ColDelta))
Cells(LR3, ColISD).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(LR3, ColISD), Cells(LR2, 
ColISD))

Range(Cells(LR3 + 1, ColTPR), Cells(LR2, ColTPR)).Value = "0"
Range(Cells(LR3 + 1, ColAccRev), Cells(LR2, ColAccRev)).Value = "0"
Range(Cells(LR3 + 1, ColPTD), Cells(LR2, ColPTD)).Value = "-"
Range(Cells(LR3 + 1, ColPP), Cells(LR2, ColPP)).Value = "0"
Range(Cells(LR3 + 1, ColPT), Cells(LR2, ColPT)).Value = "-"
Range(Cells(LR3 + 1, ColAccruals), Cells(LR2, ColAccruals)).Value = "0"
Range(Cells(LR3 + 1, ColCMF), Cells(LR2, ColCMF)).Value = "0"
Range(Cells(LR3 + 1, ColTPOA), Cells(LR2, ColTPOA)).Value = "0"
Range(Cells(LR3 + 1, ColSTBD), Cells(LR2, ColSTBD)).Value = "0"

 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(FR, ColUID), Cells(LR2, LC)).RemoveDuplicates 
Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

With Application
 .ScreenUpdating = True
 .DisplayStatusBar = True
 .EnableEvents = True
 .DisplayAlerts = True
End With
 ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

 AddsComplete = MsgBox("The line items which were in your 'KOB1' but not your 
'Report' tab have been successfully added." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "The 
'KOB1' tab is filtered to the items that were just added.", vbOKOnly, "Additions 
Complete")

 End If
 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**